# Unable to Programmatically invoke the invisible recaptcha challenge by ID

Tags: invisible-recaptcha

We have a set up with multiple forms on a single page. We are rendering each recaptcha successfully, however I'm struggling to invoke the recaptcha challenge programatically targeted to an ID.

Looking at the docs (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute) my understanding is that I can pass an ID with the execute command so the response is filled into g-response within the correct form, otherwise the response defaults to the first g-response it finds on the page (which is no good for anything other than the first form on the page).

I've tried it with a slightly modified version of Googles own example, however we get the error message 'Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js: recaptcha123' even though the key is correct.

Does anyone have any idea how we might get this working?

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>

    function onSubmit(token) {
      alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('field').value);
    }

    function validate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
            alert("You must add text to the required field");
        } else {
            grecaptcha.execute('recaptcha123');
        }
    }

    function onload() {
      var element = document.getElementById('submit');
      element.onclick = validate;
    }

  </script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form>
      Name: (required) <input id="field" name="field">
      <div id="recaptcha123" class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
          data-callback="onSubmit"
          data-size="invisible"></div>
      <button id="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>onload();</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>

    <script>

        var onSubmit = function(token) {
            console.log('success!');
        };

        var onloadCallback = function() {
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'callback' : onSubmit
        });
        };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script src="/wp-content/themes/kc_water_care_services/js/pristine.min.js"></script>


    <form action="?" method="POST" id="contactForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name (required)</label>
            <input type="text" required data-pristine-required-message="Please enter your name"
            id="name" name="name" />
        </div><!--/.form-group-->
        <div id="recaptcha" data-size="invisible"></div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


<script>

var form = document.getElementById("contactForm");

// create the pristine instance
var pristine = new Pristine(form);

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // check if the form is valid
    var valid = pristine.validate(); // returns true or false

    if(valid == true){
      grecaptcha.execute(widgetId1);
    }

});

</script>
```

Turns out the id doesn't refer to the css ID, it refers to an ID created when you use the render function.